# Batch file don't work when double clicked

Tags: batch-file, mysql

I got a batch file to do mysqldump.  The code is like this:

```
@echo off
echo Starting Backup of Mysql Database on server 
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do set myDate=%k%i%j
set bkupfilename=%myDate%.sql
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump  --routines -u <user> -p<pwd>  <database> > D:\MYSQL_DAILY_BACKUPS\"<database>%bkupfilename%"
```

When I run it on cmd console in Win7 by typing the batch file, it won't work and complain about:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldumpbatch
Starting Backup of Mysql Database on server
kj was unexpected at this time.
```

But when I run it by copy pasting the code directly to command prompt it run just fine and produce file 20152401.sql.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single % variant only works from the command line. Try replacing with %% like so:

```
@echo off
echo Starting Backup of Mysql Database on server 
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set myDate=%%k%%i%%j
set bkupfilename=%myDate%.sql
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump  --routines -u <user> -p<pwd>  <database> > D:\MYSQL_DAILY_BACKUPS\"<database>%bkupfilename%"
```

Let me know if that works?

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for the edit, it's been a while since I've been shell scripting in Windows.

Comment: So close! the doubling of the `%` is required on the *metavariables* (loop-control variables `%%i`,`%%j`,`%%k` but must *not* be placed around an ordinary environment variable. `%%mydate%%` here for instance would become the literal "%mydate%`, not the contents of the variable `mydate`. There is a special instance, `call echo %%mydate%%` which may sometimes be used within a block to access the run-time value of `mydate` but it's not necessary here since no block is involved (edited to suit).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! Great job on properly formatting your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!